# query with group by and count in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

My query:

```
select id_posizione as posizione, IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE as transazione, Count(IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE) as count_transazioni
from  GP_TRANSAZIONI
group by id_posizione, IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE order by id_posizione;
```

returns this result:

```
POSIZIONE       TRANSAZIONE                             COUNT_TRANSAZIONI
264             35afec5d-a71e-56f6-94d9-vf111b7f7f27    3
265             51afec5d-c71e-46f6-94d9-fb221b7f7e65    1
265             69b04d6d-ef58-417c-b070-2d2c2da778ff    2
266             51afec5d-c71e-46f6-94d9-fb221b7f7e66    3
267             98c6fa08-7c85-49e6-9c1e-52bdd80c6bb2    7
268             146f9355-13f1-4fb2-a2e6-b55588e312fd    4
269             3a85ff57-54bf-4b0d-b2fd-3f69aa239467    3
270             03899fe7-607b-457f-bcfb-570c1511b33a    4
271             47ffb07b-b410-4591-ad89-f8b820ba0a85    2
```

I'd like to extract only "POSIZIONE" with different "TRANSAZIONE". In the return data above only "POSIZIONE" 265 has two "TRANSAZIONE" . I would like to extract only 265 "POSIZIONE".

Comment: POSIZIONE TRANSAZIONE                                             COUNT
264   35afec5d-a71e-56f6-94d9-vf111b7f7f27         3
265   51afec5d-c71e-46f6-94d9-fb221b7f7e65 1
265   69b04d6d-ef58-417c-b070-2d2c2da778ff 2
266   51afec5d-c71e-46f6-94d9-fb221b7f7e66 3
267   98c6fa08-7c85-49e6-9c1e-52bdd80c6bb2 7
268   146f9355-13f1-4fb2-a2e6-b55588e312fd 4
269   3a85ff57-54bf-4b0d-b2fd-3f69aa239467 3
270   03899fe7-607b-457f-bcfb-570c1511b33a 4
271   47ffb07b-b410-4591-ad89-f8b820ba0a85 2

Comment: You could add a Where clause and specify count greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the meaning of your question. 
Either you need to simply add a `having` to filter on aggregate column:

```
select id_posizione as posizione, IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE as transazione, Count(IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE) as count_transazioni
from  GP_TRANSAZIONI
group by id_posizione, IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE 
having Count(IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE)>1
order by id_posizione;
```

which will return

```
264     35afec5d-a71e-56f6-94d9-vf111b7f7f27    3
265     69b04d6d-ef58-417c-b070-2d2c2da778ff    2
266     51afec5d-c71e-46f6-94d9-fb221b7f7e66    3
267     98c6fa08-7c85-49e6-9c1e-52bdd80c6bb2    7
268     146f9355-13f1-4fb2-a2e6-b55588e312fd    4
269     3a85ff57-54bf-4b0d-b2fd-3f69aa239467    3
270     03899fe7-607b-457f-bcfb-570c1511b33a    4
271     47ffb07b-b410-4591-ad89-f8b820ba0a85    2
```

Or you need to refactor a little bit your query by adding `count(distinct xxx)` and the `having` keyword like that:

```
select id_posizione as posizione, Count(distinct IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE) as count_transazioni
from  GP_TRANSAZIONI
group by id_posizione 
having Count(distinct IDENTIFICATIVO_TRANSAZIONE)>1
order by id_posizione;
```

which return

265     2

Comment: Thank you. The last answer is what I was looking for